# How to limit sources for Entries field set up via migration

Tags: entries-field, migration, sources

I'm seeting up all of my project's fields using migrations.
This works really well, but I haven't been able to figure out how to limit the sources (sections) for an entry selection field.

I've based my work on this [migrations example](https://github.com/vend/craft3-migration-examples/blob/master/migrations/m180717_214112_faq_entry_matrix_block.php), which contains the following code:

```
new \craft\fields\Entries([
    "name" => "Questions",
    "handle" => "questions",
    "instructions" => "Choose one or more questions",
    "sources" => ["section:" . $questionsSection->id],
    "limit" => 10,
    "required" => false,
    "selectionLabel" => "Select Questions",
]),
```

However, I don't get how I can add *multiple* sections as allowed sources… can anybody clarify how to do this?

Comment: Could you add your update as an official answer instead of an update to the original question?

Comment: @BradBell, done. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

After getting some feedback from *Craft* support it turns out one has to use `uid` instead of `id` for this to work:

```
"sources" => ["section:" . $questionsSection->uid],
```

Since I had a lot of places in my migration where I needed to specify sources, I included a couple small functions:

```
/* --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- */

protected function _section_id($sectionHandle)
{
    return Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle($sectionHandle)->uid;

} // _section_id()

/* --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- */

protected function _source($handle, $kind = 'section')
{
    $source = $kind . ':' . $this->_section_id($handle);
    return $source;

} // _source()

/* --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- */
```

You can then limit the entries field sources like so:

```
"source" => null,
"sources" => [
    $this->_source("sectionA"),
    $this->_source("sectionB"),
],
```

(Note that I'm additionally setting `"source" => null` as per a plugin-created migration I analyzed, but not sure if it's required.)